# Data decoded from Base64 by a PowerShell script is corrupt in some cases

Tags: powershell, base64

Working with some binary data encoded in Base64 I used the below powershell script to convert back to binary. It worked well with for example PDF files encoded by C# code for including in XML documents.

But now I tried to use the same script with a different kind of binary data - text encrypted with PGP using Bouncy Castle library for .NET. And the files this decodes cannot be decrypted (PGP error 34), even though when the same Base 64 string below is saved in a SQL database `varchar(max)` column, I read it back and decrypt just fine. Why would PowerShell decode Base64 differently than c# code? Both are using .NET...

```
$b64      = '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'
$filename = '1.bin'

$bytes = [Convert]::FromBase64String($b64)
[IO.File]::WriteAllBytes($filename, $bytes)
```

Answer (score 0):

(Just thinking out load here)

More information may be needed here.  Your code is taking the string and converting it to raw binary, and outputting that to a file.  If you then re-import it, and convert it back, it is working.

Have you tried taking the data from both processes and comparing the output?  One may have a header for example, while the other doesn't.

Comment: I've thought about doing that, but what value would there be in that test, if I found that binary data produced by production code and the script above was different? I was thinking that PGP error 34 was evident enough of it being different, so did not bother writing a test harness.

Comment: Ajeh:  I'm suspecting the problem is not in the encoding as much as it may be headers.  For example, a certificate request requires the "--Begin" syntax.  Is there a missing header or similar that keeps the raw data from being read is where I was going with the question.

Comment: ASCII armor is off.